Is it possible to integrate Azure AD B2C into a legacy .net framework 4.8 application?
Ì want to to integrate Azure AD B2C into a legacy application which is programmed with .Net Framework v4.8. The thing is that I really can't find anything on the internet that works for that framework.
I also tried solutions from ChatGPT but surprise they didn't work either.
Does anyone did this already and can give me some tips and tricks for the integration?
Thank you.
Edit: The answer from Jeff was exactly what I needed. It's also the same as in the Tutorial which was mentioned from Panagiotis in the comments. Have a look here.

I'm pretty sure you can. AAD B2C uses OpenID Connect (or SAML I guess), so as long as you can use that, you can use AAD B2C.

Did you try checking the documentation instead of ChatGPT? Azure AD B2C was released before .NET Framework 4.8 itself. Multiple Azure AD libraries have come and gone and Azure AD itself is now called Entra

@Panagiotis - of course but I stuck with packages that i couldn't integrate because the framework v4.8 wasn't supported.

Check this question  which in turn redirects to the doc guide and ASP.NET Framework sample configured to use Azure AD B2C. The way that guide is written doesn't make it clear this is not a Core project, but the sample code is.

In general, Azure docs will cover more platforms than .NET docs, and will have ready-made samples for most cases. The Azure SDKs change (relatively) frequently though, so the names used today may not be the same as those in the samples.

Yes - you can. I still have an ASP.Net Framework MVC application running that uses B2C. Here's a quick overview of how I added B2C to my existing application.
Add an OWIN startup class following the instructions here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana#host-owin-in-iis
The example I followed (years ago) set up a class named Startup as a partial class, split between the Owin startup class in the example (mine is Startup.cs) and a file named Startup.Auth.cs in the App_Start folder. (If I could still find the example - I would just link to it, but I can't - so I'm including the relevant code.)
My Startup.cs looks like this:
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // this controls the claim type that is used to populate User.Identity.Name
        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "emails";
        
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}

My Startup.Auth.cs looks like this (almost completely from the example):
public partial class Startup
{
    /*
    * Configure the OWIN middleware
    */

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
            CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "emails",
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}",

                // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            }
        );
    }

    /*
     *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
     *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
     */
    private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(Globals.DefaultPolicy))
        {
            notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(Globals.DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    /*
     * Catch any failures received by the authentication middleware and handle appropriately
     */
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();

        // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
        // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
            // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
        }
        else if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90091"))
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
        }
        else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    /*
     * Callback function when an authorization code is received
     */
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            /*
             The `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` is created and hooked in the `UserTokenCache` used by `IConfidentialClientApplication`.
             At this point, if you inspect `ClaimsPrinciple.Current` you will notice that the Identity is still unauthenticated and it has no claims,
             but `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` needs the claims to work properly. Because of this sync problem, we are using the constructor that
             receives `ClaimsPrincipal` as argument and we are getting the claims from the object `AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context`.
             This object contains the property `AuthenticationTicket.Identity`, which is a `ClaimsIdentity`, created from the token received from
             Azure AD and has a full set of claims.
             */
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity));

            // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
            AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Globals.Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ReasonPhrase = $"Unable to get authorization code {ex.Message}."
            });
        }
    }
}

I have these values in my web.config appSettings section (obviously - replace with your values from the App Registration):
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="tenantname.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="hidden" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="hidden" />
<add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="hidden" />
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tfp/{0}/{1}" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://homepageurl" />
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="b2c_1_susi" />
<add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="b2c_1_edit_profile" />
<add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="b2c_1_reset" />

You can see a couple of places that I'm using "emails" to populate User.Identity.Name. You can specify a different claim if you want to.

Thanks for that answer @jefftrotman! But I have a question: How can I get my user attributes from the claims that are in the Id-Token?

Take a look at the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8.1#examples

MSAL is the official library from Microsoft to integrade OIDC/AD/AD B2C login into your own application.
A lot of different frameworks are supported, also desktop applications written in WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#desktop
Example code for WPF can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API
However these examples are for AD, usually there is an option in the MSAL configuration whether you talk to AD or AD B2C or just any other OpenID Connect IDP.
If you have any specific problems to use that code I suggest to open a dedicated question for that with details+code what does not work in your app.
